# Converting labels in line shapefile to annotation using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.3, annotation

I need to convert labels on multiple shapefiles containing streets, to annotations. I browsed for some time and almost every post refers to Tiled Labels To Annotation (Cartography) function (TiledLabelsToAnnotation_cartography), but it only lets me convert labels on polygon shapefiles. I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1 with a Basic level license.

How can I convert my labels in non-polygon shapefiles, using that function or any other method?

Comment: There’s a tool for that in ArcGIS Pro - see https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/cartography/convert-labels-to-annotation.htm - but that functionality may only have been available via the GUI for ArcMap.

Comment: Be aware that shapefiles do not support annotation while geodatabases do.

Comment: Sadly, it seems that tool is that im looking for, but its not available